# How do I go back to IIS Express after loading Regular IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am running VS 15 and I was able to run IIS Express from the http://localhost/index.html  (no port numbers) just fine.  I had to remove the port numbers because a program I am testing does not handle port numbers in a localhost named website correctly.  This was working just fine.

I had to load IIS manager (and its components) so that I could create a SSL certificate request.  I did this successfully but now localhost(no port number) will not work for IIS Express.  I would like to use IIS Express locally but I need to run this project without port numbers.  IIS Express with a port numbers still works correctly.

I removed IIS manager from my system using the "Windows Feature Manager".  Rebooted but I am still not able to http://localhost/ for my project.  I receive a 404 error.  i think IIS must still hold a connection to that specific location for some reason.

1. How can I just get it to work again?

Comment: Have you completely uninstall IIS and Windows Activation Service?

Comment: I used the windows feature manager and I went back and checked that everything in there for the IIS side were unchecked.  I think there may be a hidden reference hanging onto it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can choose IIS Express inside Project Properties

1. Right Click to Project
2. Select Web
3. Change to "ISS Express" in dropdownlist

Comment: The problem is something is locking onto the the http://localhost/index.html  So that when Express tries to use it is not found.

Comment: You can change the starting url as well in project properties.

Comment: I changes the starting url.  I actually had this working fine as http://localhost/index.html until I enabled IIS then it seemed like it took control of the localhost local dns

Comment: It's quite weird then, I suggest you could create another web application project in visual studio and try to run to test if it is really IIS express issue. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Weird creating a new project with it's url set as localhost worked.  I went back to my original project and now localhost with no port numbers works correctly.  Its like it reset something.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for someone else in the future. 
1. Make sure that IIS and the corresponding World Wide Web items are uninstalled from the Windows Activation Feature list
2. Try a new project and set it to localhost/
3. Go back to the original Project and try again.

It seems to be some sort of "reset" like effort is needed to get IIS Express to respond again.